# jQuery timer runs fast across more than one tab or window

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, counter

I've created a jQuery time counter that uses local storage to update a span tag to display the timer count across different tabs and windows. It works well except it seems to run faster than the expected 1000 milliseconds (second) intervals when the site is open in more than one tab or window. I can't fault the script. It runs well here, but when I implement it locally and run it across more than one tab or window, it runs fast and sometimes counts in increments of 2 seconds. Can anyone emulate this issue locally?

UPDATE: After some further testing, the timer increases with each tab or window that is opened. One tab or window is good, 2 or more tabs increases the timer x 2, but this is also inconsistent. Could the local storage be updated independently within each tab?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
        count = count + 1;

        var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
        var seconds = count - minutes * 60;

        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        $("#timer").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    }

    $(document).on("keypress click tap scroll", function () {
        count = 0;
        localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem("count") !== null) {
        count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));
    }

    $(window).on("storage", function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.key === "count") {
            count = parseInt(e.originalEvent.newValue);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer">0:00</span>
```